# how to calculate the integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to calculate the following integral: for positive constants $a_1, \cdots, a_{n+1}, $ and $i>0$
$$
\int_{S^n\bigcap\{u_m\geq 0,\  m=1,\cdots, n+1\}}\left(\sum_{m=1}^{n+1} \frac{u_m}{a_m}\right)^{-i}du,
$$
where $u=(u_1, \cdots, u_{n+1})\in S^n,$ the unit sphere.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried **evaluating** it for some small $n$? Do you think the method can be generalized to any $n$?

Comment: Try it out of some values, **may** is not enough to be sure.

Comment: The evaluating process  may be the same for any $n.$ In fact,  I need it may less than  $$C(\frac{a_1\cdots a_{n+1}}{a_2\cdots  a_{n+1}})^i$$ if $a_1\leq\cdots\leq a_{n+1}.$